# Jquery mobile grouping buttons and input box

Tags: jquery-mobile

In JQuery Mobile, I am trying to group buttons with an input box in the middle.
Below is my code

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a href="#" data-role="button">Yes</a>
        <input type="text"  value="0" min="0" max="20" size="2"  />
        <a href="#" data-role="button">Maybe</a>
    </div>
```

This is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjpK5.jpg)

Any ideas would be great?

Comment: And how do you want it to look?

Comment: Hi Zalk, basically you will have a button on either side (left and right) of the input box

Answer (score 1):

The radio buttons need an aggressive case of display:inline !important; ... Here is a list with 2 lines, one normal buttons and one mini's.

Hope it helps.  http://jsfiddle.net/den232/5mVv8/

```
    .floatleft {
    float:left;
 }
.floatright {
    float:right;
 }
.forceinline{  /* Prevent fieldcontain from doing a BLOCK thing */
    display:inline !important;
}
.textwidth {  /* limit width of input fields */
    width:80px;
}
.closespacing { /* controls spacing between elements */
    margin:0px 5px 0px 0px;
 }
.bigselect {   /* centers select with big buttons */
    padding: 0px;
    margin:2px 5px 0px 0px;
 }
.biginputheight {   /* matches text input height to big buttons */
    padding-top:10px !important;
    padding-bottom:12px !important;
}
.miniinputheight { /* matches text input height to minibuttons */
    padding-top:5px !important;
    padding-bottom:5px !important;
}

<div data-role="page" class="type-home">
```

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">first LI line</li>
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">

    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class= 'forceinline'>
      <div class='floatleft closespacing'>    
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
          <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-a" value="aa"  />
          <label for="radio-view-a">A1</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-b" value="bb"  />
          <label for="radio-view-b">B1</label>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div  class='floatleft textwidth'>
      <input type="text" placeholder="left" class='biginputheight'></input>
    </div>  

  </li>
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">

    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class= 'forceinline'>
      <div class='floatleft closespacing'>    
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini='true'>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-a" value="aa"  />
          <label for="radio-view-a">AA</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-b" value="bb"  />
          <label for="radio-view-b">BB</label>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div  class='floatleft textwidth'>
      <input type="text" placeholder="e2" class='miniinputheight'></input>
    </div>  

     <div class='floatright closespacing'>
      <div  class='floatright textwidth'>
        <input type="text" placeholder="e3" class='miniinputheight'></input>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </li>
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">last LI line</li>

</ul><!-- /listview -->
```

Answer (score 0):

By default buttons take up the entire width of the view port. Try using the data-inline attribute to change that.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-inline.html

You'll also need some css to get the input looking right. The following seemed to work for me. You'll probably need to adjust the width depending on what you're going for.

```
input.ui-input-text {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Hi Josh, no that does not seem to work, the issue is the input box, removing the input box, the buttons align correctly.

Comment: Hi Josh, I created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rayray/k9DtT/2/ . Still cant get it to work with your changes.

Comment: Not sure then. I see what you're saying about the jsfiddle but when I throw the exact same code into an empty page locally it works.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me and hope it helps someone else seeking the same.

```css
.controlgroup-textinput{
    padding-top:.22em;
    padding-bottom:.22em;
}
```

```html
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="false">
    <a href="#" data-role="button">Yes</a>
    <input type="text"  value="0" min="0" max="20" size="2" data-wrapper-class="controlgroup-textinput ui-btn" />
    <a href="#" data-role="button">Maybe</a>
</fieldset>
```